# How to get Method name in c# as a string?

Tags: c#

In Java we can get the method name using the Method in java.lang.reflect API. For example

```
public void GetmethodName(Method method)
{
  String testName = method.getName();

}
```

Can I achieve this using the refection API or Diagnostics API in c#

Comment: What is the expected value of `testName` here? I don't want to make any assumptions, although I *think* I know what you're after.

Comment: Dont use reflection in C# 6 and up, use `nameof(MethodName)` instead.

Comment: @Fixation oh, there are plenty of times when `MethodInfo`-based reflection is entirely appropriate; really it depends on context (which we don't have here)

Comment: I understand that, but I dont see why we recommend reflection before mentioning `nameof()`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=netframework-4.8)

```
public void GetmethodName([CallerMemberName] string methodname = null)
{
  Console.WriteLine(methodname);
}
```

When using `CallerMemberNameAttribute`, the compiler directly hard code (check the `ldstr` instruction) the method name during compilation and would not require reflection. For example,

```
void Foo()
{
    GetmethodName();
}
```

Looking at the IL Code

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldstr       "Foo"
IL_0007:  call        UserQuery.GetmethodName
IL_000C:  nop         
IL_000D:  ret
```

Comment: that IL looks like it is in debug mode; it will be even terser without that, especially if you make `GetmethodName` static

Comment: @MarcGravell good catch, yes thats true. It is in debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

Very similarly:

```cs
public void GetMethodName(MethodInfo method)
{
  string testName = method.Name;
}
```

where you can get the `MethodInfo` via a `Type` instance, i.e. `typeof(Foo).GetMethod(...)` or `someTypeInstance.GetMethods(...)`

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get the methods name using reflection:

```
using System.Reflection;

// ...

public class MyClass
{    
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        MethodBase m = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod();

        // This will write "MyClass.MyMethod" to the console
        Console.WriteLine($"Executing {m.ReflectedType.Name}.{m.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're after the *current* method's name, you wouldn't do that though; you'd just write a `static string CurrentMethodName([CallerMemberName] string caller = null) => caller;` and just do `string whoAmI = CurrentMethodName();` - or just `string whoAmI = nameof(TheMethodYouAreIn);` (if you just want to avoid a string literal)